# Ubuntu on usb - very slow on Asus?

Tags: usb, live-usb, asus, startup-disk-creator

I am a bit of a noob and trying to get ubuntu to run on an usb-stick, but it is painfully slow. If I make a live-usb with no persistence it works great. But if I add persistence it is very slow. Also tried installing on an usb-stick but this is also very slow.
This is on my Asus NJ550JK. I have managed to get a live usb with persistence running fine on anonter weaker machine.
Does this make sense? Any advice?

Comment: Could you please post the fact that using "something other than Startup Disk Creator" (maybe clarifying *what* exactly) solved the problem for you as an answer to the question? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, sorry but can not provide more info. I followed a tutorial long time ago, that described how to create a stick with more than 4gb persistence. This one worked fine, but I can not get startup disc creator to work well with persistence (slow as in so slow somethings wrong).
So I have given up on sticks with persistence for now.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious recommendation here is to try a different OS for the live USB. Try [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm), which is designed for this use case.

To speed up Firefox, in case you're just using that, try the recommendation here, which has worked for me: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox_on_RAM

> - open about:config in the address bar
> - set browser.cache.disk.enable to "false" (double click the line)
> - verify that browser.cache.memory.enable is set to "true" (default value)
> - add the entry (right click->new->integer) browser.cache.memory.capacity and set it to the amount of KB you'd like to spare, or to -1 for automatic cache size selection. (Skipping this step has the same effect as setting the value to -1.)

This tells firefox to not use the disk to cache any files, since reads and writes from the USB are slow compared to a hard disk.

Another useful method could be to switch off swap using `sudo swapoff -a`. This is not advisable for your system as you may not have enough RAM to support the entire OS, but if it fails, it will lead to system instability and will reset on reboot.